# Display service with list format

Tags: linux, bash

i'm searching a way to display output of `service --status-all` command with a list formatting (like `ls` does)

I've saw few tips using `prinf` but i don't hunderstand anything :s

The idea is to have something like :

```
Status     Service Name     ||    Status    Service Name
 [ + ]     Apache                  [ + ]    cntlm
 [ + ]     MySQL                   [ + ]    cron
 [ - ]     casper
 [ ? ]     irqbalance
```

Instead of

```
[ + ]    Apache
[ + ]    cntlm
[ + ]    cron
[ + ]    MySQL
[ - ]    casper
[ ? ]    irqbalance
```

Any idea ? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pr` command can do that.

```
echo "$input" | pr -2t
```

gives

```
[ + ]    Apache                     [ + ]    MySQL
[ + ]    cntlm                      [ - ]    casper
[ + ]    cron                       [ ? ]    irqbalance
```

while

```
echo "$input" | pr -2at
```

gives

```
[ + ]    Apache                     [ + ]    cntlm
[ + ]    cron                       [ + ]    MySQL
[ - ]    casper                     [ ? ]    irqbalance
```

- `-2` means 2 columns
- `-a` means "across"
- `-t` skips page headers

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the `column` command like this:

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | column -c 70
```

(The `2>&1` part in the `service` command will redirect those services with unknown status to the standard output instead of *stderr*, thus avoiding that `[ ? ]` services are listed apart)

The `-c 70` in the `column` command indicates that you want columns 70 chars wide (at least that is what is specified in the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html))